# building an encrypted key repository in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, encryption, keystore

Are there any tutorials on building an encrypted key repository using objective c? I would like to have encrypted content in an iPhone application, but the application will not have network access. All of the content will be embedded in the application as packaged. I could simply hardcode decryption keys or dynamically generate the decryption key using some algorithm in memory. But I've read that both of those techniques are easily hackable. Instead, I'd like to see if I can abstract my keys one level further by implementing a key-store/key-repository. Are there any good pointers?

Answer (score 1):

How large is the data you are looking to encrypt?  If it's small data like passwords, then your best bet is to store them in the Keychain.  If it is larger data then you will probably need to prompt the user to enter their own secret encryption key.  That encryption key could then be stored safely within the Keychain and of course retrieved when it is time to decrypt your data.

Answer (score 0):

I use [SFHFKeychainUtils](https://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/master/security) which stores data in the built-in Keychain. It's designed mainly for passwords, but I extended it to support storing arbitrary property lists. Your primary disadvantage with the keychain is that it's not necessarily backed up (it's only backed up to the computer if encrypted backup is enabled in iTunes), so some users might lose their encrypted data (especially if migrating to newer hardware).